# Use Spring Boot with Gatling

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance-testing, gatling

Is it possible to run Gatling as part of the Spring project? I am very used to the coding style of Spring (beans etc.) and I would like to use those to refactor the code in Gatling. Is it possible?

I run my Gatling simulations with

```
gradle gatlingRun
```

and it just looks for the simulation classes, sends the requests and creates report. It is very different from how the Spring application runs. Is there anyway to combine those?

Comment: You would need something to start the application before gatling is run. As you are using gradle that shouldn't be to hard (like adding a depends, or a custom task that first starts the app). Drawback is that you are now running the app **and** the tests on the same machine, which will impact the performance (and probably heavily).